# Use Moq to mock Constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, constructor, moq

I have such a set of Constructors:

```
public BusinessObjectContext()
         : this(CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString").TableEndpoint.ToString(),
                CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString").Credentials) {}

public BusinessObjectContext(string dataConnectionString)
         : this(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(dataConnectionString).TableEndpoint.ToString(),
                CloudStorageAccount.Parse(dataConnectionString).Credentials) { }

public BusinessObjectContext(String baseAddress, StorageCredentials credentials) 
         : base(baseAddress, credentials) { }
```

However when testing / Mocking I need the object without any of the connection string parameters. How can I do this - preferrably in Moq?

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds as if you have a code smell - the [constructor is doing too much work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). The article includes  a set of fixes for such scenarios. Basically the answer is to *only* perform assignment in constructors, not execute business logic.

Comment: Hrrm. I see the argument in this concept.
On the other hand I wanted to shield the user of the object GenericBusinessObject from thinking about the Data Source Context. 
If I follow your arguments, then the user of the GenericBusinessObject has to think about it. This is less abtraction. 
Maybe there is no other way, but something makes me hesitate.

Comment: Make a factory or use an IOC Conatainer to remove this need for the user to worry about the Data Context.

Answer (score 40):

```
var myMockBOC = new Mock<BusinessObjectContext>(null, null);
```

This will pass nulls in for your two parameters.

Another approach would be to create an internal constructor meant for test usage only, and use [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to allow your test assembly to use it.  Unfortunately this has a big drawback in that if you sign your assemblies, [Moq is unable to use the constructor](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=203).  This is supposed to be addressed in the 4.0 release of Moq though.

Comment: The drawback to an internal constructor is that now you're writing code to support your unit tests.

Comment: I would argue that that is acceptable when there is a purposeful requirement that the *public* API not be injectable.  The only time it would present issues would be if your constructors were not simplistic, and contained business logic - then, as the saying goes, you would have two problems...

Comment: Very simple solution! Helped me a lot!

Comment: I am not sure this would work if class is sealed

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use your constructor parameters you might pass with It.IsAny() method while you mocking it. It would pass null value to it. It would be much more readable when you use this method instead of writing null.

Answer (score 0):

Use factory and remove the two first constructors. Access `CloudStorageAccount` from the factory. Even better, hide `CloudStorageAccount` behind an interface because now it seems like you are using static methods.