# How can I get moq to ignore a function?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to mock out a class in Moq with this method:

```
public virtual void Init(Context context, IPrincipal user)
{
    _context = context;
    _user = user;

    var u = _context.Users.Include("Foo").First(x => x.Login == _user.Identity.Name);
```

My code that is calling this looks like this:

```
mockLoginState.CallBase = false;
mockLoginState.Setup(x => x.Init(It.IsAny<Context>(), It.IsAny<IPrincipal>()));
```

I don't want this method to actually be called because it will hit the database.  From what I understand about Moq, this should be stubbed over because it's virtual and the code in the function shouldn't run, but this is not what I'm experiencing.  Basically my problem is exactly as is described here:
["Short circuiting" void methods with Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203529/short-circuiting-void-methods-with-moq?rq=1)
but the answer to that question didn't work for me.

How do I stop the function from being called?

Comment: You're not actually using the `.Verifiable()` / `.Verify()` detailed in the accepted answer on your linked question. If you add those, does it skip your method?

Comment: Can you post your full test, please? You'll need to inject `mockLoginState.Object` as the instance of this dependency to your SUT, or if this class is your SUT, you'll need to invoke the method being tested on the `mockLoginState.Object` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Your code above looks correct. Are you sure you're calling the `Init` method on the Mock object? Have you tried using `MockBehavior.Strict` when constructing your `Mock<LoginState>`? This should throw an exception if any method that you haven't explicitly set up gets called.

Otherwise, you might have to provide more of your code for context.

Answer (score 0):

Joe Taylor's answer was a clue.

Apparently the `Init` function was being called in the constructor of my LoginState object.  When I created the `Mock<LoginState>` it was being called, and therefor my override was happening too late.

For more information on dealing with this constraint, see this question:
[Use Moq to mock Constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976018/use-moq-to-mock-constructor)